XML in browser with inline CSS doesn't work
I am trying to use CSS inside XML but it seems browser doesn't like it yet.
I tried this example from W3 and nothing happened:
<?xml-stylesheet href="#s1" type="text/css"?>
<doc>
  <s id="s1">
    s { display: none }
    p { display: block }
    p[warning="yes"] { color: red }
  </s>
  <p>Some text... </p>
  <p warning="yes">A note... </p>
</doc>

It is still shown as a tree or just inline text.

display: none for the style rules element needs to be the last rule
<?xml-stylesheet href="#s1" type="text/css"?>
<doc>
  <s id="s1">
    p { display: block }
    p[warning="yes"] { color: red }
    s { display: none }
  </s>
  <p>Some text... </p>
  <p warning="yes">A note... </p>
</doc>


Only works in FireFox
